# Disable beep when editing stylesheet notebooks

Tags: front-end, customization

When editing stylesheet notebooks that are bound to a currently open notebook, the front-end emits an incredibly annoying beep with every key-stroke.

To see this in action, run this:

```
Module[{nb, sd},
 nb = CreateDocument[];
 FrontEndTokenExecute["EditStyleDefinitions", nb];
 sd = Lookup[NotebookInformation[nb], "StyleDefinitions"][[1]];
 {nb, sd}
 ]
```

and edit the notebook with `WindowTitle` `"Style Definitions for Untitled-__"`

I've tried numerous options to get it to go away, but it seems to be bound to the fact that the stylesheet is being used by a different notebook.

Is there anyway to disable this?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem. Can you give a detailed (step-by-step) description on how you created it?

Comment: @m_goldberg happy to

Comment: I also do not reproduce the beep (MMa 11.2.0 on Win7 x64).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov interesting. So when you type in private style sheets you get no noise? Does the “Why the Beep?” dialog say anything for you? For me it says something about being unable to edit a style cell (which isn’t true).

Comment: I don't see “Why the Beep?” dialog and edit without any noise. But probably I unchecked "beep on errors" setting somewhere a long time ago, I vaguely remember...